# Decompose 2 basic factors from a risk severity

Tags: algorithm, matrix, integration, differentiation

I have 2 matrices of values:

Matrix A size 2x4 and matrix B size 2x4 as follows:

Main Matrix B Scales

```
0.00    2.50   
2.50    5.00  
5.00    11.25   
11.25   25.00
```

the other matrix A is:

```
0.00    1.25  
1.25    2.50  
2.50    7.50  
7.50    25.00
```

and can be of any values.

When we multiply 2 variant numbers of values from (0 to 5) we get a value that we can represent in matrix A levels (between the limits of any level).  We can represent the outcome of multiplication of (x,y) into the second scale (matrix) to be on the same level (line 1 or line 2 or line 3 or line 4) by the following operation:

- We get the known outcome of multiplied known numbers (x and y) and we see on what level it goes in matrix A (lets say level 3).
- We need to map it to be on matrix B on the same level (level 3).
- we map the value (result of X*y) that lies in level z in matrix A to matrix B by doing the following math: (result-minimum value of the level it lies in)/ (max level value - minimum level value)) and we get a percentage outcome.  this outcome we use it as:

(the percentage outcome * (maximum limit of the mapped level in the matrix B -minimum limit of the mapped level in matrix B)/100) +  minimum limit of the mapped level in matrix B

the new mapped value lies in matrix B on the same level where the original value lies in matrix A.

my question what are the best representative values of 2 variables a and b where a* b = the new mapped value in matrix B.
where a>= x and b>= y

**Example**:

x=2, y=2.8 the value is (2*2.8=5.6 this is lets say in Matrix B), now we do the calculation above and get the new value to be mapped into matrix A = 8.87. What we need is to decompose the new 8.87 to another x and y where when we multiply them we get the new value 8.87

This should be generic to any x and y values and any matrix A and B, etc.

more examples are: x= 1.5 y=3 severity = 1.5*3 = 4.5 this lies in level 3 of matrix B. the new mapped severity calculation is 7.499 and lies in level 3 of matrix A. the question what are the 2 numbers that we need to multiply (a,b) to get the number 7.499 on matrix A

more examples are: x= 3 y=2 severity = 3*2 = 6 this lies in level 3 of matrix B. the new mapped severity calculation is 9.374 and lies in level 3 of matrix A. the question what are the 2 numbers that we need to multiply (a,b) to get the number 9.374 on matrix A

more examples are: x= 1.2 y=2 severity = 1.2*2 = 2.4 this lies in level 2 of matrix B. the new mapped severity calculation is 4.799 and lies in level 2 of matrix A. the question what are the 2 numbers that we need to multiply (a,b) to get the number 4.799 on matrix A

Comment: Added formatting and corrected typos for better readability. Could you add the language you're trying to implement this algorithm in? Also please add what you have tried so far.

Comment: there are infinite (a,b) pairs where their multiplication is a given number. Do you have any limitations or some kind of relations between (x,y) and (a,b) ? Like x+y=a+b or x/y=a/b ?

Comment: btw the matrices are 2x4 not 2x5 and based on your examples I think the first one is matrix A and the second one is matrix B

Comment: @RiyadM.Jaddal (1) Clarifications and examples belong in your posting, not in comments.  Edit your posting and make a table out of those examples; (2) Get your math accurate; for instance, the target number in your first example is 7.5 even, not 7.499

Comment: Please reduce the posting to a description of the problem you're trying to solve, not the entire paradigm.  As posted, your question reduces to finding numbers **a, b** in the range [1, 5] whose product is a given number.  As @Selindek pointed out, there are infinite solutions.  Also, this is trivial algebra, even with the restrictions.